# /etc/hosts Cannot point hostname to new ip

Tags: dns, hosts, nameserver

Under Linux, the `/etc/hosts` file can be used to override DNS definitions, i.e. to point a hostname to a different IP.

I need to test a new VPS. So I added a line in the /etc/hosts file:

```
123.123.123.123 www.mywebsite.com
```

I flushed all caches and went to www.mywebsite.com , but it still shows the old site. In the new site, I should see the default apache file "It Works!"

I used ping to test the ip and it shows the new ip.

I used wget to retrieve the index.html file, but it retrieves the file from the old server.

I use DNS Flusher Firefox add on to clear DNS cache. I also check using Midori browser private browsing (it doesn't cache DNSs).

For testing purposes, I added a line for facebook:

```
123.123.123.123 www.facebook.com
```

I works fine, i.e. I see a "connection timed out" message, after a redirection from `http://` to `https://`

I added another line:

```
123.123.123.123 stackoverflow.com
```

This time, I see the normal stackoverflow website.

If I add:

```
127.0.0.1  www.mywebsite.com
```

I see a not found message from local server.

I checked using Windows and saw the same behaviour.

Why can't I point a hostname to a new IP?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: I bypassed my router to check if it¡s something related with it, but it isn't.

Comment: Juan: Do you have `nscd` running on your computer? ⫽ @Flimm: Which doesn't make much sense, since the entire question is about *overriding* DNS. `host` does not use the generic name lookup functions that wget or a browser would.

Comment: @grawity: Huh you're right about `host`.

Comment: Test your DNS using `ping example.com` and `getent hosts example.com` on the command-line.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have `nscd` installed.

Comment: `ping mywebsite.com` gives me the new IP. `wget mywebsite.com` shows me the old website.

Comment: I'd strace the wget, find out where it's looking

Comment: Have a look at your environment variables, too.

Comment: Did you edit the host file on the server or the client?  The host file needs edited on EVERY CLIENT.  Also, have you setup named virtual host correctly and put in and configured the sites-available files and made the links in sites-enabled?

Comment: Thanks. Wumpus, how would I trace wget? Damon, I have nothing installed in the new server, so nothing to configure yet.

Comment: Since I'm not able to solve this: does anyone know how to point an address to a different ip using a proxy server (I'm using Ubuntu)?

Comment: Additional info: I added  123.123.123.123 www.mywebsite.com in the /etc/hosts file of a remote server and wget www.mywebsite.com shows me the contents of the new server. so the problem is local